# jquery json decimal rounding

Tags: jquery, json, rounding, quandl

im pulling data from quandl and doing some calculations. the issue is the result goes upto 15 decimal points. is there any way that could be done to limit this to two?

```
<script>
var apikey = "myapikey";
var url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/"
var database = "BSE/BOM532667";
var parameters = ".json?auth_token=";
var fullUrl = url + database + parameters + apikey;
jQuery.getJSON(fullUrl, function (data1) {
$('#value1').html((data1.data[0][4]-data1.data[29][4])*100/data1.data[0][4]);
</script>

1-Month return (%): <span id="value1"></span><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
// ((data1.data[0][4]-data1.data[29][4])*100/data1.data[0][4]).toFixed(2)
$('#value1').html(((data1.data[0][4]-data1.data[29][4])*100/data1.data[0][4]).toFixed(2));
```

This will reduce your decimal points to 2 from any number of points.

Comment: i had tried the usual jquery rounding options already, sadly they didnt work.

Comment: toFixed is javascript function so it will work , doesn't depends on jQuery , there might be some brackets error , please check again.

Comment: Will you please show us the output of (data1.data[0][4]-data1.data[29][4])*100/data1.data[0][4]

Comment: hey it worked .! thank u very much..
i tried for almost an hour with d same thing... but for strange reasons it didnt.!

Comment: @SolitaryReaper , LOL will you please upvote the answer and accept it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numObj.toFixed([digits])` for round.

> toFixed() returns a string representation of numObj that does not use exponential notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place. The number is rounded if necessary, and the fractional part is padded with zeros if necessary so that it has the specified length. If numObj is greater than 1e+21, this method simply calls Number.prototype.toString() and returns a string in exponential notation.

Examples

```
var numObj = 12345.6789;

numObj.toFixed();       // Returns '12346': note rounding, no fractional part
numObj.toFixed(1);      // Returns '12345.7': note rounding
numObj.toFixed(6);      // Returns '12345.678900': note added zeros
(1.23e+20).toFixed(2);  // Returns '123000000000000000000.00'
(1.23e-10).toFixed(2);  // Returns '0.00'
2.34.toFixed(1);        // Returns '2.3'
2.35.toFixed(1);        // Returns '2.4'. Note that it rounds up in this case.
-2.34.toFixed(1);       // Returns -2.3 (due to operator precedence, negative number literals don't return a string...)
(-2.34).toFixed(1);     // Returns '-2.3' (...unless you use parentheses)
```

Comment: .tofixed(2) for strange reasons doesnt work. im getting the same usual 15 numbers after the decimal part